# DateTime Add calculation inside Linq to entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am trying to add datetime in Linq query.

> Error is : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.DateTime AddMinutes(Double)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

It is working in Link to SQL but not working to LINQ to Entity.

Is there any another way to do this.

Thanks

```
DataClassesDataContext datacontext = new DataClassesDataContext();
        int concertid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlConcerts.SelectedValue.ToString());
        GridView1.DataSource = (from ticketallocation in datacontext.tblConcertTicketAllocation
                                where ticketallocation.ConcertID == concertid
                                && ticketallocation.Section == ddlSection.SelectedValue
                                && ticketallocation.Row == ddlRows.SelectedValue
                                select new
                                {
                                    AutoID = ticketallocation.AutoID,
                                    ConcertID = ticketallocation.ConcertID,
                                    Section = ticketallocation.Section,
                                    Row = ticketallocation.Row,
                                    Seats = ticketallocation.Seats,
                                    Status = ticketallocation.Status == 3 ? "<span style=\"color:#FF0000;\">Sold</span>" :
                                    ticketallocation.Status == 2 ? "<span style=\"color:#999999;\">Aisle Break</span>" :
                                    ticketallocation.Status == 0 ? "<span style=\"color:#009900;\">Available</span>" :
                                    ticketallocation.Status == 1 && ticketallocation.DateandTime.Value.AddMinutes(16) > DateTime.Now ? "<span style=\"color:#FF9900;\">Looking</span>" : "<span style=\"color:#009900;\">Available</span>",
                                    DateandTime = ticketallocation.DateandTime,
                                    OrderNumber = ticketallocation.OrderNumber
                                }).ToList();
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 10):

In **EntityFramework 6** EntityFunctions are gone.

Use

```
System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions
```

instead

This isn't answer to the OP question, but maybe it helps to some incoming viewers.

Comment: "+1 thanks." ...  Seriously though, this just simplified a _ton_ of our business logic.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Entity Framework v4, try this code

```
System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(ticketallocation.DateandTime.Value, 16)
```

instead of

```
ticketallocation.DateandTime.Value.AddMinutes(16)
```

If you are using Entity Framework v1, the solution is [Entity SQL Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx), e.g., like it is described in [this post](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/56/performing-date-and-time-arithmetic-queries-using-entity-framework-v1).

Comment: Unfortunately you can not rely that all the providers implement this canonical functions. In my case it doesn't work with Sybase.

Comment: I see so much talk about SqlFunctions, that I've never heard of the EntityFunctions (and I've been doing alllooot of reading recently) - thanks Devart.

Answer (score 0):

You can used: System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions